# Saving search engine parameters: design consideration

Tags: visualforce, future, design

I have a custom search engine for my limited users. These users have a custom front end and we cannot have them seeing the objects through the standard UI.

One of the new requirements that I have is to save the data used in each search (including some advanced filters etc) so that we can see what people are searching for, how they are searching and how often.

This search is already using quite a lot of time so I was thinking of pushing the save of the data to a future method.

Obviously I don't actually know but I think that this search is used frequently by a lot of users (hence the metrics). This is called from a visualforce controller so I know that each instance will contain a single call but is a future method not a good direction to go? The chances of having multiple instances of the future method is extremely likely.

Comment: If you are always inserting and not updating and it is only one future call per request then it makes sense. But you may burn a lot of space (at the 2k minimum per row) if the search really is used a lot if you do an insert for each individual search.

Comment: Yes, that what I was thinking. I've put a custom setting in place as a traffic cop. We can turn on search analytics for a week, export the data, turn off the analytics and delete the data from SFDC.